# Unable to use Map.Keys() function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm able to create and manipulate a `Map` object, but I do not have access to the `.keys()` or `.values()` functions.

How can I figure why this is?

```
let a = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]);
a.set('c', 3);

let myArray = a.keys();
```

I get red underline under `keys()`.

Error:

```
[15:52:12] Error - typescript - src\...TruckDeliverySchedule.tsx(102,21): error TS2339: Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'Map<string, number>'.
```

I'm not sure what else would be relevant.  Very new javascript programming.

EDIT:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      //"es2015.collection"  // removed
      "es2015"
    ]
```

EDIT 2:

Project was built for a Sharepoint Framework and using Visual Studio Code.

When I try to look at the definition for `Map`, I takes me to:

```
// Backward compatibility with --target es5
declare global {
    interface Set<T> { }
    interface Map<K, V> { }
    interface WeakSet<T> { }
    interface WeakMap<K extends object, V> { }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure what to post.  I try to type out myMap.keys() and I get an error.  Unless I do a screen shot, doesn't much help.

Comment: Sounds like your `tsconfig.json` might be weird.  What do you have in the `compilerOptions.lib` property?

Comment: I would guess there is something fishy with your tsconfig. Did you try to explicitly define the type of "a" in the first line, like this?

`let a:Map<String, Number> = new Map(...`

Comment: @ChristianEngel I just tried that and still throwing an error on `.keys()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `compilerOptions` for your `tsconfig.json` file, you have:

```
"lib": [
  "es5",
  "dom",
  "es2015.collection"
]
```

So [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) was introduced in ECMAScript 2015, but you are explicitly including only the [`es2015.collection`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.1/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts) TypeScript library, instead of the [library for all of ECMAScript 2015](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.1/lib/lib.es2015.d.ts). 
The particular methods you are missing are present in the [`es2015.iterable`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.1/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L111-L129) library. I'd suggest that, if you are targeting an environment that supports all of ES2015, you should change `es2015.collection` to `es2015` so you get the whole thing instead of just pieces of it.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm doing this for Sharepoint Framework project.  This is the default values that the project is set up with.  I did change it tfrom the `es2015.collection` to just `es2015` and still throwing the error.

Comment: It should work, so your editor/compiler is not seeing the modification to the tsconfig.  Either you changed it in the wrong place, or the editor/compiler is using a stale version.  Not sure how to help you other than to suggest you make sure you are using the right tsconfig file and possibly refresh your editor/compiler to make sure it's not stuck

Comment: Ha!  you were right.  Restarted VSCode and its working.  Thank you bud, much appreciated!